# IdentityServer4 not considering PersistedGrants store (user_consent in particular)

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 service that stores the `Configuration` and the `PersistedGrants` in a SQL Server DB using the built in Entity Framework support.
My client is using the Hybrid grant, and supports PKCE (if it matters).
Whenever I try to login again after a successful login attempt that consisted the consent screen, with the same user to the same client - I always get a redirection to the consent screen again.
I made sure my client's `AllowRememberConsent` is set to true in the Clients' table, also I can see the consent in the PersistedGrants table with the desired ClientId and SubjectId. 
Moreover, whenever I consent again - the same record gets updated with the new CreationTime and of course Data column.
I compared my configuration to the one in the official documentation quickstart that works, and still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask for `offline_access` - the consent screen will always get shown.

This is to make sure the user is aware that the app is asking for long time access to resources. IOW - if the app asks for offline access, which results in a refresh token, there is no reason to ask for it again any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me see if I follow.
Does that mean that if the user asked to log out from the app, then logged in again which results in generation a new refresh token (since the old one is not valid anymore, or at least it shouldn't be), the consent screen will be shown again?
The user has already consented to the terms, why does he need to approve them again?

Comment: Is logout from an app really a common use case? Typically you want to login once to an app and then can use it "forever" (or at least some extended period of time).
But I can see your point - if you think this is a common scenario please open an issue on github so we can discuss this.

Comment: This feature is crucial for us since our app contains sensitive data and access to financial operations. We want to make a user log-in at least once a day so I can validate his identity. We do use refresh tokens but I don't want to make them live for more than a day. Thanks, I will open an issue on github.