# Permission grant page will always be shown when using IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I've set up a MVC application and the IdentityServer as desribed in the quickstarts. I also use EFCore to persist the confiuration and grants.

Everything works fine, even the Windows authentication.

When I logout from my MVC app using

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("oidc");
}
```

I'm logged out as expected.

But when I login again, enter my credentials and click "Login" the next page asking for the permission grants, again. But why? I already set the permissions on my first login. How can I avoid that?

This can be very annoying if I try to implement a SSO using Windows authentification.

Does this problem means that the grants won't be persisted and read from the database?

Comment: Are you saying the Consent Page is showing again?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Found the same problem here

[IdentityServer4 not considering PersistedGrants store (user_consent in particular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764925/identityserver4-not-considering-persistedgrants-store-user-consent-in-particula)

So he already opened an issue https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/928

Answer (score 1):

When creating you're client you can turn off consent with the RequireConsent Flag and you can remember it by adding AllowRememberConsent to true

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",
    AllowRememberConsent = true
}
```

you can see the documentation [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html)

Comment: Even with `AllowRememberConsent = true`, if you ask for another RefreshToken (set the scopes to contain `offline_access`, the user will have to consent again. See Dominick's answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764925/identityserver4-not-considering-persistedgrants-store-user-consent-in-particula